# React Native Mobile Application Security Test

Tags: react-native, security, testing, mobile

After archive react-native ios appication, I had test it on Immuniweb mobile application testing tool. I have got security issue given bellow.

EXPOSURE OF POTENTIALLY SENSITIVE DATA [DAST] [M2] [CWE-200]
Potentially sensitive or internal information is detected in the mobile application via tracing its system calls.
[POTENTIAL HEROKU API KEY FOUND]

We did not use HEROKU anyway.

This is my package.json contents.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "rn-nodeify --install fs,util,path,tls,stream,buffer,global,process --hack && patch-package",
    "android": "ENVFILE=.env react-native run-android",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.3",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.9",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^8.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@rneui/base": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@rneui/themed": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "asyncstorage-down": "^4.2.0",
    "aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.12",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1203.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "buffer": "^4.9.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.max": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.min": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.unionby": "^4.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.69.2",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.6",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-encrypted-asyncstorage": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-iap": "^11.0.0-rc.7",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.3",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.25.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "readable-stream": "1.0.33",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rn-swipe-button": "^1.3.7",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "util": "~0.10.3",
    "victory-native": "^36.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "react-native": {
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "tls": false,
    "fs": "react-native-fs"
  },
  "browser": {
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "tls": false,
    "fs": "react-native-fs"
  }
}
```

I need help to overcome this security issue?